# How to access (get ans set) to the mipmap in the foreground of a floating action button inside the activity

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

I've set the foreground of my FAB with a mipmap and i'd like to access it from my activity.
I need to get the current reference of the mipmap (id or name) and use it as a condition in order to change the foreground mipmap on each click.

Here is the xml of my FAB :

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/selection_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="228dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:foreground="@mipmap/im_check_green_white"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:contentDescription="@string/selection_fab"/>
```

The code below, written in my activity, doesn't work as expected.
The method to set a new mipmap works well, but not the one to get it and conditions never match  :

```
private void setupSelectionFab() {
    
    Drawable fgCur = selectionFab.getForeground().getCurrent();
    Drawable fgGreen = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.mipmap.im_check_green_white);
    Drawable fgGrey = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.mipmap.im_check_grey_white);

    if (fgCur.equals(fgGreen)) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "inside condition 1");
            selectionFab.setForeground(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this,R.mipmap.im_check_grey_white));
        } else if (fgCur.equals(fgGrey)) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "inside condition 2");
            selectionFab.setForeground(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this,R.mipmap.im_check_green_white));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there's no reference to `drawable` resource IDs in the `Drawable` itself - creating them from a resource is just one way you can instantiate them, it's not common to all `Drawable`s. And two different instances of `Drawable` aren't *equal* so you can't compare them like that.

Why not just keep track of the current state in your code?

```
boolean checked = false;

// I assume this happens on a click
private void setupSelectionFab() {
    // toggle checked status
    checked = !checked;

    // display the appropriate drawable
    int resId = (checked) ? R.mipmap.im_check_green_white : R.mipmap.im_check_grey_white;
    selectionFab.setForeground(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, resId));
}
```

Comment: Thank you Cactustictacs ! 
Much more simple and efficient. It's exactly what i expected. 
I wonder why, sometime, i make it so complicated ! :-)